# Visual Basic Sterling ActiveX Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, activex

I'm new to Visual Basic, and I'm having trouble with a program that I'm working on. I'm using the Sterling ActiveX library to create a basic functional program that does an easy task (sending an order) for the Sterling Trader software. I'm just trying to make something basic that works and that I can build off of. Here's my code so far:

`Imports SterlingLib`

Public Class Form1

```
Dim WithEvents m_STIEvents As STIEvents

Private Declare Sub GetLocalTime Lib "kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Private Structure SYSTEMTIME

    Dim wYear As Short

    Dim wMonth As Short

    Dim wDayOfWeek As Short
    Dim wDay As Short
    Dim wHour As Short
    Dim wMinute As Short
    Dim wSecond As Short
    Dim wMilliseconds As Short
End Structure

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    m_STIEvents = New STIEvents

End Sub

Private Sub m_STIEvents_OnSTIOrderUpdateMsg(ByVal oSTIOrderUpdateMsg As SterlingLib.STIOrderUpdateMsg) Handles m_STIEvents.OnSTIOrderUpdateMsg

    Dim order As STIOrder
    order = New STIOrder
    Dim storder As structSTIOrder

    storder.bstrAccount = "ACCT7"
    storder.bstrSide = "B"
    storder.bstrSymbol = "CSCO"

    order.Quantity = "500"
    storder.bstrStrPriceType = SterlingLib.STIPriceTypes.ptSTIMkt
    storder.bstrTif = "D"
    storder.bstrDestination = "NYSE"

    Dim theTime As SYSTEMTIME
    GetLocalTime(theTime)

    storder.bstrClOrderId = storder.bstrAccount & theTime.wYear & theTime.wMonth & theTime.wDay & theTime.wHour & theTime.wMinute & theTime.wSecond & theTime.wMilliseconds

    Dim ret As Integer

    ret = order.SubmitOrder



End Sub

Private Function Text1() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
```

End Class

When I run this program, I get the following error:
"Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {5E89F49B-6A12-420F-8570-E510EF1B580A} failed due to the following error: 800700c1."

What does this mean, and how can I correct it? When I debug, it highlights "m_STIEvents = New STIEvents" as the line where things are going wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse-engineer the error code, 0x800700c1.  If not through Google then by design.  The 8 makes it an error.  The 7 is the "facility code", where the error originated, 7 means Windows.  Which makes the last 4 digits a Windows error code.  0x00c1 = error 193.  Which you can lookup many ways, one is by looking at the Windows SDK's WinError.h file:

```
//
// MessageId: ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT
//
// MessageText:
//
// %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
//
#define ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT             193L
```

The kind of error code that's invariably generated on a 64-bit operating system.  Running 64-bit code and trying to load a legacy 32-bit ActiveX component.

Which suggests the easy fix: right-click your EXE project in the Solution Explorer windows.  Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced Compile Options button.  Change the Target CPU setting to "x86" to force your VB.NET code to run in 32-bit mode so it can load that ActiveX control.  Or if it is already set to x86 then change it to "AnyCPU" to take care of the oddball chance that this is a 64-bit ActiveX control.

Contact the vendor of the component if that didn't work or you have any additional problems.

Comment: I don't have any options exactly like what you're describing. There's an option that says "Target framework (all configurations):"
My options are: .NET Framework 2.0, .NET Framework 3.0, .NET Framework 3.5, .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile, .NET Framework 4.0, .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, and Install other frameworks.

Is that it? And which one should I select?

Comment: You are on the wrong tab.  Use the Compile tab, as documented in the answer.  Scroll down to find the "Advanced Compile Options" button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved this problem. The way I solved it was installing vb6 on my computer. I tried all the other ways and none of those works. This API is pretty old. Install vb6 solved my problem. Also if you want the program work, you have to login sterling trader pro. Good luck.